# What are the tradeoffs in passing lambda functions?

Tags: c++, c++14

I still don't have a great grasp of perfect forward and move references. I'm trying to understand the differences in regards to passing lambda expressions around. My assumption was that I'd use `std::function<..>` or `auto` to accept lambda function types, but then looking at the [Folly source code](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Synchronized.h) I see that they're using function templates.

I wrote a small test program to try and understand the differences, with both lvalue and rvalues, but I can't see any. Are there any differences between the `SetLambda*()` variants below?

As far as I can tell, the only one which doesn't work is `SetLambda5()` when given an lvalue. For reference, I'm using a GCC version supporting C++14.

```
struct MyClass {
  template<typename Lambda>
  void SetLambda(Lambda&& lambda) { mLambda = std::forward<Lambda>(lambda); }

  template<typename Lambda>
  void SetLambda2(Lambda&& lambda) { mLambda = lambda; }

  template<typename Lambda>
  void SetLambda3(Lambda lambda) { mLambda = lambda; }

  void SetLambda4(auto lambda) { mLambda = lambda; }
  //void SetLambda5(auto& lambda) { mLambda = lambda; }
  void SetLambda6(auto&& lambda) { mLambda = lambda; }
  void SetLambda7(std::function<void()> lambda) { mLambda = lambda; }

  void Run() { mLambda(); }
  std::function<void()> mLambda;
};

int main() {
  auto lambda = []() { std::cout << "test0\n"; };

  MyClass myClass;
  myClass.SetLambda([]() { std::cout << "test1\n"; });
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda(lambda);
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda2([]() { std::cout << "test2\n"; });
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda2(lambda);
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda3([]() { std::cout << "test3\n"; });
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda3(lambda);
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda4([]() { std::cout << "test4\n"; });
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda4(lambda);
  myClass.Run();
  //myClass.SetLambda5([]() { std::cout << "test5\n"; });
  //myClass.Run();
  //myClass.SetLambda5(lambda);
  //myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda6([]() { std::cout << "test6\n"; });
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda6(lambda);
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda7([]() { std::cout << "test7\n"; });
  myClass.Run();
  myClass.SetLambda7(lambda);
  myClass.Run();

  return 0;
}
```

And, for reference, the output:

```
test1
test0
test2
test0
test3
test0
test4
test0
test6
test0
test7
test0
```

Comment: If you're storing the lambda in a `std::function` to call later then taking a `std::function` would be most appropriate. If you're going to call it right away without storing it then `SetLambda3` is the way to go (it's what all the standard algorithms use).

Comment: Apologies, I was fixing the question as you answered it. I think you meant SetLambda7() if I'm going to call it later. Why does Folly use function templates?

Comment: Folly, the C++ standard library and others use function templates for performance. If you have a function template that takes a callable and just calls it, there is no indirection. The compiler can inline the call. You're literally just injecting code without the inefficiency of `std::function`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When accepting an unknown functor that you're going to call directly without storing it, the ideal, value category preserving way to do so is:

```
template <typename Func>
void DoAThing(Func&& func) {
    std::forward<Func>(func)(parameters);
}
```

When you want to store the functor in a `std::function` object to call later, just accept a `std::function` and let the implicit conversion do most of the work for you:

```
void StoreAFunctor(std::function<void()> func) {
    myFunctor = std::move(func);
}
```

---

Before diving into a deeper explanation, the first thing to mention is that the point of using move semantics and perfect forwarding is to avoid doing expensive copy operations.  We want to move ownership of resources around when possible instead of unnecessarily copying them.  If your objects don't own any movable resources (as is the case of a lambda with no captures), then none of this matters.  Just pass the object by reference-to-const and copy it as needed.  If your objects *do* own some movable resources, then things get hairy.

Before talking about lambdas and `std::function`, I'm going to take a step back and look at how things work with this simple type that shows what's going on:

```
struct ShowMe {
  ShowMe() { }
  ShowMe(const ShowMe&) { std::cout << "ShowMe copy constructed\n"; }
  ShowMe(ShowMe&&) { std::cout << "ShowMe move constructed\n"; }
  ShowMe& operator=(const ShowMe&) { std::cout << "ShowMe copy assigned\n"; return *this; }
  ShowMe& operator=(ShowMe&&) { std::cout << "ShowMe move assigned\n"; return *this; }
};
```

I'm also going to use this simple type as a stand-in for `std::function`:

```
struct ShowMeHolder {
  ShowMeHolder() { }
  ShowMeHolder(const ShowMe& object) : mObject{object} { }
  ShowMeHolder(ShowMe&& object) : mObject{std::move(object)} { }
  ShowMeHolder& operator=(const ShowMe& object) { mObject = object; return *this; }
  ShowMeHolder& operator=(ShowMe&& object) { mObject = std::move(object); return *this; }

  ShowMe mObject;
};
```

Using that type, here's an example that reproduces all of your test cases (plus a few variants):

```
struct MyClass {
  template<typename Object>
  void SetObject(Object&& object) { mObject = std::forward<Object>(object); }

  template<typename Object>
  void SetObject2(Object&& object) { mObject = object; }

  template<typename Object>
  void SetObject3(Object object) { mObject = object; }

  template <typename Object>
  void SetObject3Variant(Object object) { mObject = std::move(object); }

  void SetObject4(auto object) { mObject = object; }
  void SetObject4Variant(auto object) { mObject = std::move(object); }
  void SetObject5(auto& object) { mObject = object; }
  void SetObject6(auto&& object) { mObject = object; }
  void SetObject6Variant(auto&& object) { mObject = std::forward<decltype(object)>(object); }
  void SetObject7(ShowMeHolder object) { mObject = object; }
  void SetObject7Variant(ShowMeHolder object) { mObject = std::move(object); }

  ShowMeHolder mObject;
};

int main() {
  MyClass myClass;
  ShowMe object;

  std::cout << "SetObject move\n";
  myClass.SetObject(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject2 move\n";
  myClass.SetObject2(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject2 copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject2(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject3 move\n";
  myClass.SetObject3(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject3 copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject3(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject3Variant move\n";
  myClass.SetObject3Variant(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject3Variant copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject3Variant(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject4 move\n";
  myClass.SetObject4(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject4 copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject4(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject4Variant move\n";
  myClass.SetObject4Variant(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject4Variant copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject4Variant(object);

  //std::cout << "SetObject5 move\n";
  //myClass.SetObject5(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject5 copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject5(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject6 move\n";
  myClass.SetObject6(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject6 copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject6(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject6Variant move\n";
  myClass.SetObject6Variant(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject6Variant copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject6Variant(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject7 move\n";
  myClass.SetObject7(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject7 copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject7(object);

  std::cout << "SetObject7Variant move\n";
  myClass.SetObject7Variant(std::move(object));
  std::cout << "SetObject7Variant copy\n";
  myClass.SetObject7Variant(object);
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
SetObject move
ShowMe move assigned
SetObject copy
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject2 move
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject2 copy
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject3 move
ShowMe move constructed
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject3 copy
ShowMe copy constructed
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject3Variant move
ShowMe move constructed
ShowMe move assigned
SetObject3Variant copy
ShowMe copy constructed
ShowMe move assigned
SetObject4 move
ShowMe move constructed
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject4 copy
ShowMe copy constructed
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject4Variant move
ShowMe move constructed
ShowMe move assigned
SetObject4Variant copy
ShowMe copy constructed
ShowMe move assigned
SetObject5 copy
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject6 move
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject6 copy
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject6Variant move
ShowMe move assigned
SetObject6Variant copy
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject7 move
ShowMe move constructed
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject7 copy
ShowMe copy constructed
ShowMe copy assigned
SetObject7Variant move
ShowMe move constructed
ShowMe move assigned
SetObject7Variant copy
ShowMe copy constructed
ShowMe move assigned
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/603ff5c0f320a2bf)

I'll go through each and explain why they behave the way they do:

- `SetObject`:  This function accepts a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references).  When combined with `std::forward` these preserve the value category of the object passed to them.  That means that when we call `SetObject(object)` `object` gets copy-assigned from and when we call `SetObject(std::move(object))` `object` gets move-assigned from.
- `SetObject2`: This function accepts a forwarding reference, but since you didn't use `std::forward` to preserve the value category of the parameter it is always an lvalue, and therefore copy-assigned from.
- `SetObject3`: This function accepts its parameter by value.  The parameter object is either copy or move constructed based on the value category of the object passed to the function, but then the parameter object is always copy-assigned from since it is an lvalue.
- `SetObject3Variant`: This function, like `SetObject3` accepts its parameter by value and the parameter object is either copy or move constructed based on the value category of the object passed to the function.  We then use `std::move` to cast the parameter object to an rvalue causing it to be move-assigned from instead of copy-assigned.
- `SetObject4`: This function works exactly like `SetObject3`.  The `auto` parameter is just syntactic sugar for a template.
- `SetObject4Variant`: This function works exactly like `SetObject3Variant`
- `SetObject5`: This function accepts its parameter by lvalue-reference-to-non-const.  Those can only bind to lvalues, so you can't pass it an rvalue at all.  Its parameter gets copy-assigned from since it's an lvalue.
- `SetObject6`: This works exactly like `SetObject2`.  Again, `auto` parameters are just syntactic sugar for templates.
- `SetObject6Variant`: This works exactly like `SetObject` except that the `std::forward` syntax is a bit wonky since you don't have an explicit template type parameter to refer to.
- `SetObject7`: This function accepts a `ShowMeHolder` by value.  That object will be constructed using either the `const ShowMe&` or `ShowMe&&` constructor based on the value category of the `ShowMe` object passed to it.  The function then copy-assigns the `ShowMeHolder` parameter object to the class member since the parameter is an lvalue.
- `SetObject7Variant`: This function works similarly to `SetObject7`, but the parameter object is move-assigned from since it was cast to an rvalue using `std::move`.

---

Bringing it back to lambdas, everything works exactly the same.  Just replace `ShowMe` with some lambda type and `ShowMeHolder` with `std::function`.  There's nothing special about either of those types.  Lambdas are just objects with an overloaded `operator()`, and `std::function` is just an object that holds some other function-like object (using a bunch of tricks to be able to store *any* type of function-like object).

Comment: Does this imply that if I want to do both that I need a mixed syntax? ie template<typename T> void SetLambda(std::function<void()> saveLambda, T&& callLambda) { mSaveLambda = std::move(saveLambda); std::forward<T>(callLambda)(); }

Comment: Yes, you can mix them like that.  If you're making your function into a template to take the second functor you could avoid an extra move-assignment by taking both by forwarding reference and forward the one you want to store into the `std::function`.